# push the result of a function into an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of bills and an empty array for tips.
I'm trying to call a tipcalculator function within a for loop so I can calculate the tips of each one of the bills in the bills array, store that result in the empty tips array. Is this possible to be done?
Thanks

```js
var bills = [123,145,12,44];
var tips = [];

function calculateTips(bill){
  let tip;
  if(bill<10){
    tip = .2;
  }

  if(bill>=10 && bill <20){
    tip = .10;
  } else {
    tip = 0.1;
  }

  return tip * bill;

  for(var i=0; i<bills.length; i++){ 
    var temp = calculateTips(bills[i]);
    tips.push(temp);
  }
};
```

Comment: This quite honestly looks like a better place for `map`: `var tips = bills.map(calculateTips)` and all done

Comment: `.10` and `0.1` are the exact same value

Answer (score 0):

Your loop needs to be outside of the function. As [the documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> The **return** statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
>   be returned to the function caller.

```js
var bills = [123,145,12,44];
var tips = [];

function calculateTips(bill){
  let tip;
  
  // Since the bill will only fall into one of your tests
  // use else if, rather than an if followed by another if
  if(bill < 10){
    tip = .2;
  } else if(bill >= 10 && bill < 20){
    tip = .10;
  } else {
    tip = 0.1;
  }

  // once a function reaches a return statement
  // it will return the specified value (if any)
  // and then stop processing the function.
  return tip * bill;
}

for(var i=0; i<bills.length; i++){ 
  var temp = calculateTips(bills[i]);
  tips.push(temp);
}

console.log(tips);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `tip=.10` and `tip=0.1`. And you can shorten your script considerably, see below.

```js
const calculateTips=bill=>((bill>=10?.1:.2)*bill).toFixed(2); 
var bills = [123,145,12,44,8];

let tips=bills.map(calculateTips);
console.log(tips);
```

Fun fact: Your formula leads to higher tips for 8$ than for 12$ bills.